# Basic GPU Architecture

Tags: gpu, computer-science

I have been using CUDA for a few weeks, but I have some doubts about the allocation of blocks/warps/thread.

First of all, I would like to understand if I got these facts straight:

1. GPU has some streaming processors that can work in parallel.
2. Every SM, has Blocks, and every Block has it's own shared memory.
3. Inside Blocks we have CUDA cores.
4. And inside each SM we also have Warp schedulers.
5. Every warp consist of 32 threads. and warps inside a Block working in serial.
   It means one Warp should finish and then next Warp can start.
6. All Block in GPU cannot run in parallel at the same time. and the number of Blocks that run in parallel is limited.(But I do not know how and how many)

Now my main question is:

Assume we have 2 different situation:

1. First we have 32 Threads per block(1 warp) and we have 16384 objects(or operands).
2. Second we have 64 Threads per block(2 warps) with the same amount of objects.

Why does the first one take more time to run the program?(Other conditions are same, and even when we have 128 threads per block, it is faster than those two)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! SO is primarily intended for programming questions. Questions like yours are probably better placed on our sister site, [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/). I am therefore voting to move the question over there.

Comment: The number of concurrent blocks will not be sufficient to occupy the GPU with 32 threads per block. It requires 64 concurrent blocks to saturate which is not possible on most hardware.

Comment: Would you please explain your answer in more detail?